# Multiple file upload in angular undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, asynchronous, file-upload

I'm trying to do multiple file upload using angular 2.

This is the function I'm using to extract data to variable

**fileJSON**

, which later I push into array     **fileArray: Array = []**;.

```
  var that2 = this.fileArray;
     for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
                (function (file) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    let parts = file.name.split(".");
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        let view = new Uint8Array(this.result);
                        var data = Array.prototype.map.call(view, function (byte: any) {
                            return ('0' + (byte & 0xFF).toString(16)).slice(-2);
                        }).join('');

                        let fileJSON = { "Filename": parts[0], "Extension": parts[1], "DateCreated": new Date(), "Data": data, "TripId": "", "TypeId": 0 };

                        that2.push(fileJSON);

                    }
                    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
                })(this.files[i]);
            }
        this.editUploadedFiles();
```

After this I want to show a list of files by using

```
 <tr ng-repeat="file in fileArray">

 <td>{{file.Filename}}</td>
```

However this gives me

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Filename' of undefined

My editUploadedFiles() function where I want to get a list of all the files look like this:

```
   editUploadedFiles() {

        console.log(this.fileArray);
        this.fileArray.forEach(function (element) {
            console.log(element.Filename);
        });

        this.next(); // this just hides and shows some form div's and enables button that calls function "finish()"

    }
```

However I get the same error while trying to print out **element.Filename**.

But when I press "Next" button again, I'm calling this function caled "finish()"

```
finish() {

        this.fileArray.forEach(function (element) {
            console.log(element.Filename);
        });
    }
```

Basically its almost the same but here it shows filenames without any problems!

I think it has to do something with asynchronous operations, but I have no how to await them.

Comment: try changing `this.fileArray.forEach(function (element) {
            console.log(element.Filename);
        });` to `this.fileArray.forEach(function () {
            console.log(this.Filename);
        });`

Comment: @messerbill hey thanks for quick reaction, I'm getting " 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation" error

Comment: so try changing `this.fileArray.forEach(function (element) {
            console.log(element.Filename);
        });` to `for (let item of this.fileArray) { console.log(item.Filename) }`

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Filename' of undefined ... I don't think that function was the problem because it returns good results in the "finish" function if you see my main post

Comment: it seems that there are `undefined` elements in that array. What is the output of `console.log(this.fileArray)`?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/J9KSgwK.png Here is the image of the output.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7hokmstg/3/ - it should work with that loop

Comment: I think its because of asynchronous operations or something like that the array is not ready, is that possible?

Comment: it would be helpful if you'd provide an minimalistic example on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Well most of my code that is important is in the question, maybe you could try read there ? Because on JSFiddle its hard to do typescript code for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166322/discussion-between-user3465096-and-messerbill).

Comment: Question was not answered!

Comment: you can mark it with `bounty`s

Comment: only tomorrow I think:)

Comment: This looks like Angular JS not Angular 2

Comment: @AluanHaddad Hmm, you think so? Could you help rewrite this to angular 2 maybe?

Comment: @user3465096 angular 2 is not something you really upgrade to, it's an entirely new framework. What you're asking is equivalent to rewriting it with Vue, Aurelia, or any other SPA framework. That said, if you're not sure what framework you're writing for your not going to be able to write an app.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm using angular 2

Comment: When uploading files you should really consider using FormData and not reading the hole thing into memory. If you insist on using json to upload the files why not read the file as data url instead?

Answer (score 2):

**FAIR WARNING:** This is some of the hackiest code that I have written in a very long time. It should accomplish what you are trying to do without having to us the IIFE that you have embedded within your `for()` loop.

```js
// Your code:
/*
var that2 = this.fileArray;
for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
  (function (file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    let parts = file.name.split(".");
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      let view = new Uint8Array(this.result);
      var data = Array.prototype.map.call(view, function (byte: any) {
        return ('0' + (byte & 0xFF).toString(16)).slice(-2);
      }).join('');

      let fileJSON = { "Filename": parts[0], "Extension": parts[1], "DateCreated": new Date(), "Data": data, "TripId": "", "TypeId": 0 };

      that2.push(fileJSON);

    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  })(this.files[i]);
}
this.editUploadedFiles();
*/

// Updated code:
let fileUploadCounter = 0;

this.fileArray.map((file) => {
  const fileParts = file.name.split('.');
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (e) {
    const view = new Uint8Array(this.result);
    var data = Array.prototype.map
      .call(view, function (byte: any) {
        return ('0' + (byte & 0xFF).toString(16)).slice(-2);
      })
      .join('');

    fileReadFinished({ 
      "Filename": parts[0], 
      "Extension": parts[1], 
      "DateCreated": new Date(), 
      "Data": data, 
      "TripId": "", 
      "TypeId": 0 
    });
  };
  
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
});

function fileReadFinished(json) {
  if (fileUploadCounter === this.fileArray.length) {
    this.editUploadedFiles();
  }
}.bind(this)
```